# Is there a way to get all Discord channel messages programmatically (eg. Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to get all discord channel messages from my personal discord user account programmatically via a Python script, best case event based. It is only to find script for writing own discord bots, but this is not what I want to do...

Is there any way to do this? Maybe a ready to go python script?

Answer (score 0):

You can make an event where every message will be placed into (```py) and end with them or whatever else language you want. Im not sure about the accurate code but you can ask for help in discord servers.